# How to add Custom Token Granter to the new Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

Hello I am currently using and old Authorization Server with th end of life dependency **spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure** and now i would like to migrate to the new **Spring Authorization Server**

My questions is how can i intercept/override the default Token Granter of the new Spring Authorization Service. In the old version i just extended the AbstractTokenGranter `SsoTokenGranter extends AbstractTokenGranter`.

I would like to call other services during the token generation and add custom claims/authorities to the JWT Token with user information(Roles, Name, etc..).

Any tipps how i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an `OAuth2TokenCustomizer` can fit nicely in your use case.

```java
@Bean
public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> tokenCustomizer(
            OidcUserInfoService userInfoService) {
        return (context) -> {
            if (OidcParameterNames.ID_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType().getValue())) {
                OidcUserInfo userInfo = userInfoService.loadUser( // <2>
                        context.getPrincipal().getName());
                context.getClaims().claims(claims ->
                        claims.putAll(userInfo.getClaims()));
            }
        };
}
```

There is a [section on the reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-customizer) and a [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/51d00742f3939dbcd3b59f7c16aa9f64f1957130/docs/src/docs/asciidoc/examples/src/main/java/sample/userinfo/idtoken/IdTokenCustomizerConfig.java) that you can use as reference.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem I didn´t find any way to do that, in the old authorization server exist the token granter that allow to implement custom grant type